# Crystal report Currency Format can not be changed

Tags: asp.net

I used Crystal report Currency Format . It takes $ sign Automatically in Hosted Server .How do I change it to Rs as I am working with Indian Company

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the field/formula and go to the Format options:
[image]